# Html editorfor is not posting back data when name attribute added

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am trying to remove google autocomplete(google showing previously entered data) on an HTML editorfor, but I have not yet found the correct solution.

I am creating an asp.Net Mvc5 app.
One solution I have seen is to add a name using the Guid generator.
I have tried adding this to Html editorFor which helped remove googles suggestions, however, any data that I now enter into the HTML editorfor is not saved when I post the data back to the database.
I tried also adding autocomplete = "new- password", to the HTML editor for but it has not helped to remove google suggestions

What is wrong with the following?

> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.renovationDetail.Notes, new {
>   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", Name =
>   Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), autocomplete = "new- password" } })

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.renovationDetail.Notes, new {
>   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", Name =
>   Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), autocomplete = "off" } })

If it is not working then You can disable it via Javascript. Try it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:text,form").attr("autocomplete","off");
})
```

Comment: I am glad to help you.